# Get multiple values in single field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a query from 4 different tables and I want to concat one of the field values to one string, for instance I want the next query result

```
       **BuildName         ConfigurationName    FileName          Name   RunIDMax**
   Build_20131213.5     Default configuration   Screenshot2.png    User1        354
   Build_20131213.5     Default configuration   Screenshot1.png    User1        354
```

will appear like this:

```
     **BuildName           ConfigurationName    FileName                                 Name   RunIDMax**
   Build_20131213.5     Default configuration   Screenshot2.png, Screenshot1.png       User1        354
```

I've the following query:

```
 select * 
from (select TestPlanName, TestCaseId, AreaPath, IterationPath, TestSuiteSuitePath, ResultTestCaseId, ResultTest, ResultOutcome, max(ResultDate) as MaxResultDate , BuildName, ConfigurationName, FileName, Name, ErrorMessage, max(TA.TestRunId) as RunIDMax
from 
[Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimPerson] (nolock) AS DTRO inner join
[tfs_warehouse].dbo.TestResultView (nolock) a on  a.ResultExecutedBySK = PersonSK inner join 
[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Attachment] (nolock) AS TA ON a.TestRunId = TA.TestRunId inner join 

[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_TestActionResult] (nolock) AS TAR on TA.TestRunId = Tar.TestRunId

group by TestCaseId,TestPlanName,  AreaPath, IterationPath, TestSuiteSuitePath, ResultTestCaseId, ResultTest, ResultOutcome,  BuildName, ConfigurationName, FileName, Name, ErrorMessage) 

AS b  

where 
 ResultOutcome <> 'Never Run' and (BuildName IN (@BuildName) or @BuildName = null) and (TestPlanName In (@TestPlanName) or @TestPlanName = null)
and TestSuiteSuitePath is not null  
and BuildName is not null order by RunIDMax desc
```

And I tried to use this query:

```
select STUFF(
            (select ',' + CAST(FileName as nvarchar) 
            from [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Attachment]
            group by FileName
            for xml path('')
             ),1,1,'')
```

but I couldn't find the right way to integrate it in the main query.

Comment: It's an in-line view so you'll need to alias it. Can you post how you've attempted to integrate it? Are you getting a syntax issue, or just unexpected results?

Comment: **This is a presentation issue** so should be handled by your presentation layer e.g. report, web page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating in your query like so:

```
(select STUFF(
        (select ',' + CAST(FileName as nvarchar) 
           from [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Attachment]
          group by FileName
            for xml path('')
         ),1,1,'')) AS FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with TableCTe as
(select    'Build_20131213.5'  BuildName,   'Default configuration' ConfigurationName,   'Screenshot2.png' FileName,    'User1' Name, 354 RunIDMax
union all
select    'Build_20131213.5',     'Default configuration',   'Screenshot1.png',    'User1', 354
)
,cte1 as
(
select name,
stuff((select  ','+filename from TableCTe  for xml path('') ),1,1,'')as filename 
from TableCTe
group by name
)
,cte2 as
(select row_number()  over(order by a.name )rn, a.BuildName,a.ConfigurationName,a.Name,a.RunIDMax,b.filename from TableCTe a 
inner join cte1 b on a.Name=b.Name)

select * from cte2 where rn=1
```